# Got No Spelling Error but keep getting React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a question, after searching & reading through all possible duplicates I could not clear this issue..

So here is what I do in main.js

```
import Menu from './components/Menu' //which is Menu.js
import Item from './components/Item' //which is Item.js

<Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
        Meldungen
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item to="/test">
        Aufträge
    </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

and here my Menu.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class Menu extends Component { ... }
```

and my Item.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class Item extends Component { ... }
```

I also tried doing:

```
import { Menu } from './components/Menu'
import { Item } from './components/Item'
```

but still getting this error

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

- How could this be fixed, there are no spelling errors.
- How can I change my code so I don't have to import "Item" again in my main.js?

Comment: Doesn't an import need to be `import { Menu } from './file'`?

Answer (score 0):

if the class being exported is default then the import statement should instead be

```
import { Menu } from './components/Menu'
:

import Menu from './components/Menu';
```

Comment: yes, if not webpack would already throw an error before building

Comment: thanks but that is my first line in code of main.js - the added curly brackets were due to trying another method of importing

Answer (score 0):

There is no Item module exported from Menu.js. Therefore Menu.Item is undefined(not exported).
You can copy the code from your Item module in your Menu.js and export it too without using default.
or
Inside the directory Menu create  files

```
Menu.js
Item.js
index.js
```

keep the Menu.js and Item .js as is
and inside index.js do this:

```
import Menu from './Menu.js'
import Item from './Item.js'

module.exports = {
Menu,
Item
}
```

Now import them:

```
import { Menu, Item } from './components/Menu';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Menu.Item` ?  You are importing 2 completely separate things.

```
import Menu from './components/Menu' //which is Menu.js
import Item from './components/Item' //which is Item.js

<Menu>
    <Item>
        Meldungen
    </Item>
    <Item to="/test">
        Aufträge
    </Item>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Well the customer wants it like that

Comment: The customer is wrong, this is not a thing you can do. It leads me to ask: why does the customer require a specific (wrong) syntax for something?